# JSF Primefaces selectOneMenu component issue

Tags: ajax, primefaces

Parentpage.xhtml

```
<h:form id="newGame" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h:panelGroup id="newGameid">
    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" />
    <p:wizard id="newGameWizard" showNavBar="true" widgetVar="gameWiz" flowListener="#{javaMB.wizardFlow}">
            <p:tab id="gameTab"   title="Form">
                <ui:include src="/jsf/required.xhtml" />
                <ui:fragment rendered="#{javaMB.pageType.pageTypeId eq 1}">
                    <ui:include src="/jsf/page1.xhtml" />
                </ui:fragment>
                <ui:fragment rendered="#{javaMB.pageType.pageTypeId eq 2}">
                    <ui:include src="/jsf/page2.xhtml" />
                </ui:fragment>
            </p:tab>
   <p:tab title="Submit"   id="certifySubmit" >
                    <ui:include src="/jsf/submission.xhtml" />      
            </p:tab>
 </p:wizard>
 </h:panelGroup>
 </h:form>
```

page1.xhtml

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
 >
 <style>
 .borderClass {
 border-color: #DEEFFF;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-style: solid;
 }
 </style>
 <p:panel id="information" styleClass="panelNoBorder">
    <p:fieldset toggleable="true"  toggleSpeed="500" legend="Information">

            <p:outputLabel value="Machine Generated"/>
            <p:inputText id="machinegenerated"   value="#{javaMB.machinegenerated}"  >


            <p:selectOneMenu id="Selectpartsby" required="true" style="width:150px" value="#{javaMB.partType.partBy}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Parts By:" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{javaMB.partTypeList}" />
            <p:ajax update="other2" process="@this" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:inputText id="other2"   required="#{javaMB.partType.partBy eq 4}" value="#{javaMB.otherfield}"  >



       </p:fieldset>
    </p:panel>
 </ui:composition>
```

page2.xhtml

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
 >
 <style>
 .borderClass {
 border-color: #DEEFFF;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-style: solid;
 }
 </style>
 <p:panel id="information2" styleClass="panelNoBorder">
    <p:fieldset toggleable="true"  toggleSpeed="500" legend="Information">

            <p:outputLabel value="Manual Entry"/>
            <p:inputText id="manualentry"   value="#{javaMB.manualentry}"        >

            <p:selectOneMenu id="Selectpartsby6" required="true" style="width:150px" value="#{javaMB.partType.partBy}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Parts By:" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{javaMB.partTypeList}" />
            <p:ajax update="other6" process="@this" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

             <p:inputText id="other6"   required="#{javaMB.partType.partBy eq 4}" value="#{javaMB.otherfield}"  >



       </p:fieldset>
    </p:panel>
 </ui:composition>
```

The both the drop downs have the same values from the same table

Dropdown - Parts By
User must select an option

```
 Database
 ID name
 1 NES
 2 SONY
 3 WII
 4 OTHER
```

The inputText is required if Other is selected for 'Parts By'

The drop downs , and if the other functionality is not selected then the error for the required for the input value works fine,

The issue is  in the page 2 Upon clicking Next It does not go to the next tab

If I remove the *selectOneMenu component in the page 2* then it goes to the next tab.

I tried using the Chrome  Developer Tools, but could not find any erros,

Tried to place a debug pointer in the flowListener wizardflow method, Does not even hit it.

the page 1 works fine.

Any ideas how to fix/resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the behaviour it seems a required field missing, but since required.xhtml and JavaMB code are missing I can't tell you the real reason.
You can check, in the browser developer tool, if the ajax is returning some message/error for the growl (since it's not with auto update or updated, you can't see directly). You have also to check if the required fields are update everytime you change javaMB.partType.partBy value.